# Snort for Windows - how to get payload info out to log file, for later analysis?

Tags: snort

I am running Snort v2.9.12 for Windows.

I am getting (via -d option) payload information on console, but it is not going out to the Snort log file.  I am only getting the header information.
I modify the configuration file (\etc\snort.conf) in the output plug-ins
(step 6, around line 525).  I can get the payload in the log file via the -l (lower case L) option.
Specifying the -c option, I need to read the information back in from the log file, including the payload information.

Do I have to put in make a command line argument?

Do I have to make a configuration change?

Thank you in advance, for a solution.